# Reading .xlsx file attached to a list received using API

Tags: r, json

I use a **API to obtain an object that should contain an Excel report** that I have generated using a query saved in a webservice.
However **I do not not how to read that report into R**.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
object <- POST(url = "https://v1serv-prod.evidencepartners.com/api/v1/datarama/query", 
               add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer",key), "Content-Type" = "application/json"), 
               body = list("project_id" = as.numeric(CallAPI_QPS[1,2]), "saved_report_id" = 487, "use_saved_format"= TRUE), 
               encode = "json")
object

> object
Response [https://v1serv-prod.evidencepartners.com/api/v1/datarama/query]
  Date: 2022-07-22 07:58
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Size: 154 kB
<BINARY BODY>
```

The object is read by R as a list and should contain as an attachment the report (as a raw format I guess...).
See `..$ content-disposition` and `$ content` below

```
> str(object)
List of 10
 $ url        : chr "https://v1serv-prod.evidencepartners.com/api/v1/datarama/query"
 $ status_code: int 200
 $ headers    :List of 17
  ..$ date                            : chr "Fri, 22 Jul 2022 07:58:52 GMT"
  ..$ content-type                    : chr "application/octet-stream"
  ..$ transfer-encoding               : chr "chunked"
  ..$ connection                      : chr "keep-alive"
  ..$ cache-control                   : chr "private"
  ..$ server                          : chr "Apache"
  ..$ content-disposition             : chr "attachment; filename=487.excel"
```

...

```
 $ content    : raw [1:154362] 50 4b 03 04 ...
```

Do you know how can I **access that file**, **telling to the system that it is a .xlsx file** and so reading it into R as a separate object?
Many thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine (Angelo) gave me the solution.
I post it here since I think it can be of help for other people.
**Many thanks Angelo!**

```
library (readxl)

tmp <- tempfile()
writeBin(object = object$content, con = tmp)
ExcelReport <- read_excel(tmp)
```